# How to check if a category with a certain ID exists?

Tags: category

How can I check in a template file if a category with a certain ID exists, eg. ID 270.

I have tried the following but the statement is echoed even though there is no category 270. I'm not really sure what else to try... thanks very much for any help!

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();

if ($category->load(270)) {         
    echo "Category found";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(270);
if($category->getId()) {
    echo "Category found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this by following code:

```
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(270);
    if($_category->getId()) {
        echo "Category found";
    } else {
        echo "Category not found";
    }
```